# How to open the Excel File in without prompt & not inside browser using Servlet?

Tags: java, servlets, web-applications

I have writen the Java code to send the excel to client side. I am calling servlet from java script when the user click on the button in the page. But the File is opening in the same browser. Instead how to open the file in excel format not inside the browser without save/close dialog?

Java Script While clicking on one button

```
 window.location = url+'?Data='+Math.random();
```

Java

```
String ramdonNumber =this.getHttpRequest().getParameter("Data");
        System.out.println("Inside Action"+ramdonNumber);
        File file = new File("C:/Documents and Settings/XXXXXX/Desktop/RevisedAvailableSeatForSRESR.xls");

        try {
            this.setFileInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        HttpServletResponse response = this.getHttpResponse();
        response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/vnd.ms-excel");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
                "inline;filename=\"" + file.getName() + ".xls\";");
```

Comment: i guess this ques. has nothing to do with this code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to tell the client to show the "save as…"-dialog you should use `attachment` instead of `inline` for `Content-Disposition`.

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + file.getName() + ".xls\";");
```

More information is provided in [Chapter 19.5.1 of RFC-2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html).

Comment: Note however you cannot do this with ajax.

Comment: i need to open the file without save/cancel dialog but as seperate file. Not in the same browser from where the request has been send.

Comment: What do you mean with "seperate file". We are talking bout a browser here so you have the choice to save it as a file (`attachment`) or show it in the browser (`inline`). If you want to show it in a new window use the `_blank` target-attribute on the anchor or as parameter for `window.open`

Comment: I mean seperate file as - not inside browser. normal excel while open from our local directory.

Comment: Now I'm totally confused.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use **Apache POI** library to manipulate office documents. http://poi.apache.org/